# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unable to process binding "ifnot: function(){return customer().fullname }"

Tags: magento2.3, javascript, frontend, knockoutjs, html

Upon successful Magento upgrade to 2.4.4 from 2.4.2, I noticed the following error in browser console as site loaded. I don't see any references to this error message on the net nor in SO. Could you please help me fix this?

[image]

Image below shows where the error is originating from.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in one of your HTML templates, I can't really provide any more info without seeing all your templates.

If you search for `Welcome to Perfect Makeup Mirrors` that may help you find out where this error is occuring. The JS you posted is just showing the error in the core KO library which isn't really helpful.

Comment: This error was found immediately after Magento upgrade was done. It had never been there in the site before. So I wonder if this indicates an unsuccessful Magento upgrade.

Comment: If this is your only issue I'd consider it a very successful Magento upgrade :P

Comment: Yes, this is the only issue that I could notice across the site. But this error makes it feel bad. Entire folder search for the string doesn't show any occurrences of that text. That might be from a variable, I think

Comment: Ben, could you please have a look at the related post here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/358323/magento-2-4-2-unable-to-process-binding-ifnot-functionreturn-customer-fu? I'm struggling to fix this for over 10 days now. I added as much information about the problem as possible.

Comment: Ben, could you please have a look at the post on trouble reading active elements? Link to it is here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73364211/hide-open-active-accordion-when-another-accordion-is-clicked